# How do I reach the center of Daiba Studio's Back Alley?

Tags: tokyo-mirage-sessions-fe

Daiba Studio is best known for its teleporter rooms with its 2x5 door-layout, where going through the wrong door will teleport the party back to the starting point.

During the events of Chapter 5, I'm supposed to return to Daiba Studio to do something beyond the red door that was previously unpassable. Behind that door is the Back Alley, which is another teleporter room with a 2x5 door-layout.

Unlike the first teleporter room, the Back Alley's top and bottom half are separated. After exploring the room completely, it becomes very obvious that there is some room in between both halves of the Back Alley, a center "half" of sorts.

As a completionist, I'd like to reach that center part, but I don't know how. I tried to go through the doors from 0 to 9 in order, but that didn't work. I've already solved the dungeon by using the code given to me in the beginning, but I'm having trouble reaching the (optional?) center part of the Back Alley.

Does anybody know how to reach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chapter 6, a Mirage will appear at Daiba Studio's Back Alley Monitor Room. That Mirage will give you the request: "*What Makes a Masterpiece*". Once the request is completed, you will finally be able to access the previously inaccessible center.

Just leave the Monitor Room and enter it again to receive 3 notices about a new program being added. You will notice that 3 monitors have their number replaced by an image of Touma, Eleonora, and Yashiro. These monitors show the doors behind which you will get access to the Back Alley's center.

---

**TL;DR**
You can not reach the center before chapter 6, and you will need to complete the request "*What Makes a Masterpiece*".